# How to insert data type nvarchar more than 4000 characters in SQL Server CE?

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, nvarchar

I insert string with more than 4000 characters into a `nvarchar` column, so SQL Server CE is throwing an error.

I know `ntext` can store more than 4000 characters, but it almost support in future.

How way can I insert string with more than 4000 characters to column `nvarchar` so SQL Server CE ?

Comment: You ***CANNOT*** store more than 4000 characters into a `nvarchar` in SQL Server CE - there just is no way to do that. If you need more than 4000 characters, use `ntext` - that's what it's there for.

Comment: @marc_s : ntext is used well in clause select..where..order by ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the [data type options are limited in SQL CE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172424(SQL.110).aspx). You will need to use `ntext` to support more than 4000 characters.

> note: ntext is no longer supported in string functions.

You will not be able to compare or sort `ntext` except when using `is null` or `like`.

[The ntext and image data types cannot be used in WHERE, HAVING, GROUP BY, ON, or IN clauses, except when these data types are used with the LIKE or IS NULL predicates](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/eca752c8-f921-44cf-a35b-5ecb14cc3134/the-ntext-and-image-data-types-cannot-be-used-in-where-having-group-by-on-or-in-clauses-except?forum=sqlce)

You will be able to `select, update, delete, insert` with `ntext` as long as you are not trying to compare the value of the `ntext` column with the exception of `is null` or `like`.

So you can not:

```
update t 
set ntxt = 'I miss nvarchar(max)' 
where ntxt = 'I am using sql ce'
```

But you can

```
update t 
set ntxt = 'I miss nvarchar(max)' 
where ntxt like '%sql ce'
```

Comment: ntext is used well in clause select..where..order by ?

Comment: I am confused statement select, update, delete, insert that they can work well ???????cause I use winform to manipulate with databse